# How do I add a title property to individual jQuery array items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array list with jQuery.
I also have jQuery set up to display each item from the array as a list of clickable links.

The problem is, the links themselves are the text of the array, appended with the appropriate extension (in my case .html).

```
var links = [
"one",
"two",
"three",
"etc"
]
```

what I'm looking to do is something like

```
var links = [
href: "one" | title: "this is the first one",
]
```

so I can fetch one and display the other.

Comment: You likely need an array of `object` elements, not a simple array. `let myFirstObject = {"href":"one","title":"this is the first one"}; myLinks.push(myFirstObject);`.  Supplying your HTML would help someone give you a fuller answer.

Comment: Specifically, an array of objects, like `var links = [ { href: "one.html", title: "this is the first one" }, { href: "two.html", title: "this is the second one" }, ... ]`. But where are the titles coming from?

Comment: To expand on @Marc comment `var links = [{ href: "one", title: "this is the first one"}, { href: "two", title: "this is the second one")]`

Answer (score 0):

You could change the array to an array of Objects using the `Array.map()` method.

In the snippet below, I create an array of strings to simulate different link strings. This Array is shown in the console when ran. I then change the array to an array of objects using `Array.map()`.

I also created a helper function called `formatOrdinal()` to take a number and create an ordinal string for the title. I use this when creating the title for each item. The final array of objects is shown in the HTML page.

```js
let links = new Array(25).fill('link');
links = links.map((val, idx) => `${val}_${idx+1}.html`);
console.log(JSON.stringify(links));

const formatOrdinal = function(n) {
  const pr = new Intl.PluralRules('en-US', {
    type: 'ordinal'
  });
  const suffixes = new Map([
    ['one', 'st'],
    ['two', 'nd'],
    ['few', 'rd'],
    ['other', 'th'],
  ]);
  const rule = pr.select(n);
  const suffix = suffixes.get(rule);
  return `${n}${suffix}`;
};

links = links.map((value, index) => {
  return {
    href: value,
    title: `this is the ${formatOrdinal(index + 1)}`
  }
});

document.querySelector(`pre`).innerText = JSON.stringify(links, null, 3);
```

```html
<code>
  <pre />
</code>
```